# Can i fill empty cells in CSS Grid Layout?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've the following code:

```
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(30, 3.33%);
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}

.element1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 8;
  background-color: red;
}

.element2 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 6;
  background-color: blue;
}

.element3 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.element4 {
  grid-row-start: 6;
  grid-row-end: 8;
  background-color: green;
}

.element5 {
  grid-row-start: 10;
  grid-row-end: 12;
  background-color: purple;
}

.element6 {
  grid-row-start: 12;
  grid-row-end: 14;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Output Image:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slJgw.jpg)

And I would like to expand all the boxes that have no box on their right side, automatically like the following image:

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz5D2.png)

How could I do it without specifying manually the row where the box starts and where the box ends, just automatically.. is there any CSS propertie?

Thank you very much.

Comment: look at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid-column-row-start-end  (keyword *span* ;) ... but your HTML here is missing to demonstrate what it does and does not ;) there is also https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid-auto-flow ( keyword *dense* )

Comment: Basically you can't. That's what flexbox is for.